# How to get table from html form using rvest or httr?

Tags: r, post, web-scraping, forms, rvest

I am using R, version 3.3.1. I am trying to scrap data from following web site:

```
http://plovila.pomorstvo.hr/
```

As you can see, it is a HTML form. I would like to choose `"Tip objekta"` (object type), for example "Jahta" (Yacht) and enter `"NIB"` (which is an integer, eg. 93567). You can try yourself; just choose "Jahta" and type 93567 in NIB field.

Method is `POST`, type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I have tried 3 different approaches: using rvest, POST (httr package) and postForm (Rcurl). My rvest code is:

```
session <- html_session("http://plovila.pomorstvo.hr")
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
form <- set_values(form,  `ctl00$Content_FormContent$uiTipObjektaDropDown` = 2,
                    `ctl00$Content_FormContent$uiOznakaTextBox` = "",
                    `ctl00$Content_FormContent$uiNibTextBox` = 93567)
x <- submit_form(session, form)
```

If I run this code and get 200 status but I don't understand how can I get the table:

[image]

Additional step is to submit `Detalji` button and get additional information, but I can't see any information from x submit output.

Comment: It looks like `submit_form` is trying to use the second text box as a submit button, though I can't seem to get it to use the correct one for some reason.

Comment: i havent realized that.  i seems to me it is using correct button?

Comment: It gives me a message `Submitting with 'ctl00$Content_FormContent$uiNibTextBox'` which is not the submit button.

Comment: yeah, you are right .maybe it cam be set manualy

Comment: It can with the `submit` parameter, but I can't get the name of the button to work for some reason.

Comment: it seems this site is difficult to scrap.

Answer (score 3):

I used the `curlconverter` package to take the "Copy as cURL" data from the XHR `POST` request and turn it automagically into:

```
httr::VERB(verb = "POST", url = "http://plovila.pomorstvo.hr/", 
    httr::add_headers(Origin = "http://plovila.pomorstvo.hr", 
        `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip, deflate", 
        `Accept-Language` = "en-US,en;q=0.8", 
        `X-Requested-With` = "XMLHttpRequest", 
        Connection = "keep-alive", 
        `X-MicrosoftAjax` = "Delta=true", 
        Pragma = "no-cache", `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.34 Safari/537.36", 
        Accept = "*/*", `Cache-Control` = "no-cache", 
        Referer = "http://plovila.pomorstvo.hr/", 
        DNT = "1"), httr::set_cookies(ASP.NET_SessionId = "b4b123vyqxnt4ygzcykwwvwr"), 
    body = list(`ctl00$uiScriptManager` = "ctl00$Content_FormContent$ctl00|ctl00$Content_FormContent$uiPretraziButton", 
        ctl00_uiStyleSheetManager_TSSM = ";|635908784800000000:d29ba49:3cef4978:9768dbb9", 
        `ctl00$Content_FormContent$uiTipObjektaDropDown` = "2", 
        `ctl00$Content_FormContent$uiImeTextBox` = "", 
        `ctl00$Content_FormContent$uiNibTextBox` = "93567", 
        `__EVENTTARGET` = "", `__EVENTARGUMENT` = "", 
        `__LASTFOCUS` = "", `__VIEWSTATE` = "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", 
        `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` = "CA0B0334", 
        `__PREVIOUSPAGE` = "jGgYHmJ3-6da6PzGl9Py8IDr-Zzb75YxIFpHMz4WQ6iQEyTbjWaujGRHZU-1fqkJcMyvpGRkWGStWuj7Uf3NYv8Wi0KSCVwn435kijCN2fM1", 
        `__ASYNCPOST` = "true", 
        `ctl00$Content_FormContent$uiPretraziButton` = "Pretraži"), 
    encode = "form") -> res
```

You can see the result of that via:

```
content(res, as="text") # returns raw HTML
```

or

```
content(res, as="parsed") # returns something you can use with `rvest` / `xml2`
```

Unfortunately, this is yet another useless SharePoint website that "eGov" sites around the world have bought into as a good thing to do. That means you have to do trial and error to figure out which of those parameters is necessary since it's different on virtually every site. I tried a minimal set to no avail.

You may even have to issue a `GET` request to the main site first to establish a session.

But this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: First code (`content(res, as="text")`) gives me an error: `Error: is.response(x) is not TRUE`. Second gives me some strange text object in which I can't see any data. Why do you say this site is useless? What is your advice how to continue? How to issue a GET request t the main site? I don't know how did you get all this stuff in `httr::...`

Comment: I can't hand hold you through this. I explained the steps I took and that this is a SharePoint site which is very difficult to scrape (and it's useless because they chose to use SharePoint vs real web technologies). If you can't get this idiom to work, then look at using RSelenium.

Comment: this is probably too hard task for me. thanks for help.

Comment: you suggest to scrap it using rsillenim? whybis this better than other packahes?s